# Android values in Nexus 4 and 5X

Tags: android, layout

I know there are lot of questions/tutorials related to android layout and dimens design but I am facing one issue for the dimens. The issue is for the devices which are built with xhdpi or xxhdpi or xxxhdpi.

I have 4 values folder in my project:

1. values-sw320dp
2. values-sw420dp
3. values-xhdpi
4. values

When I run my project in Nexus 4, it loads the values from **values-sw320dp**

When I run my project in Nexus 5X, it loads the values from same folder i.e. **values-sw320dp**

Same case for Samsung galaxy s6, it also loads the values from same folder.

So, how can I separate the **values** folder for these two devices?
Can someone please help me to solve this out?

Comment: you should use values-xhdpi, values-xxhdpi

Comment: values-xxhdpi is not allowed when I build in Android Studio. It is saying me directory is not exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After lot of investigation and trial, I got solution for this. I am posting my solution here so that it can helpful to anyone in future.

Nexus 4 has a resolution of `384x640` dp with `xhdpi` density. So I used `values-sw320dp-xhdpi` for that

Nexus 5X has a resolution of `411x731` dp with `xxhdpi` density. So I used `values-sw320dp-xxhdpi` for that

Android Studio accepts it and respective devices also loads dimensions from respective values folders.

Comment: Though Nexus5 metrics shows "xdpi=422.03, ydpi=424.069", so sw420dp should still work in theory.
I saw that using sw410dp works for Nexus5X. But sw420dp doesn't